# Average element wise List of Dense vectors in each row of a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a column in a pyspark dataframe that contains Lists of DenseVectors. Different rows might have Lists of different sizes but each vector in the list is of the same size. I want to calculate the element-wise average of each of those lists.

To be more concrete, lets say I have the following df:

```
|ID        | Column                                      |
| -------- | ------------------------------------------- |
| 0        | List(DenseVector(1,2,3), DenseVector(2,4,5))|
| 1        | List(DenseVector(1,2,3))                    |
| 2        | List(DenseVector(2,2,3), DenseVector(2,4,5))|
```

What I would like to obtain is

```
|ID        | Column              |
| -------- | --------------------|
| 0        | DenseVector(1.5,3,4)|
| 1        | DenseVector(2,4,5)  |
| 2        | DenseVector(2,3,4)  |
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct pyspark function to do this. There is an `ElementwiseProduct`(which works different to what is expected here) and others [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features). So, you could try to achieve this with a `udf`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT

def elementwise_avg(vector_list):
    x = y = z = 0
    no_of_v = len(vector_list)
    for i, elem in enumerate(vector_list):
        x += elem[i][0]
        y += elem[i][1]
        z += elem[i][2]
    return Vectors.dense(x/no_of_v,y/no_of_v,z/no_of_v)

elementwise_avg_udf = F.udf(elementwise_avg, VectorUDT())

df = df.withColumn("Elementwise Avg", elementwise_avg_udf("Column"))
```

Comment: Somehow pyspark is not able to serialize and I'm getting                  
 ``` _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object```

Comment: @ruben, does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729648/pickle-picklingerror-could-not-serialize-object-typeerror-cant-pickle-thre

Comment: I had an issue on my own. The solution works. Many thanks